# How to save values in Custom Entity table - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, eav

I have created a module in Magento 2 which has **EAV structured tables**.

Created the tables and attributes by Install Schema. But I am not able to save values in to these tables.

My tables are

1. **custom_entity**

`entity_id  | attribute_set_id  | type_id  | customer_id  |created_at  | updated_at`

2. **ustom_entity_varchar**

`entity_id  | attribute_id  | store_id  | value_id  | value`

Can any one please provide me the code to save the values to the tables specified above?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: do you want CRUD operation magento 2? Please be specific.

Comment: @Dev Yes. CRUD operation magento 2

Answer (score 1):

There many links available for CRUD magento 2, below link is explain excellent. You can refer this [link](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_crud_models_for_database_access/). 
I assuming, you have created Model.
Below controller code will save values in table.

```
namespace ext\cust_module\Controller\Save;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $CustomEntityFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \<ext>\CustomEntity\Model\CustomEntityFactory $CustomEntityFactory,

    )
    {
        $this->CustomEntityFactory = $CustomEntityFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() 
    {   
        //entity_id  | attribute_set_id  | type_id  | customer_id  |created_at  | updated_at 
        // Your value in variable  
        $attribute_set_id = '';
        $msg = '';
        $CF = $this->CustomEntityFactory->create();
                $CF->setData(array('attribute_set_id' => $attribute_set_id, 'type_id' => $type_id)) 
                    ->save();
        $msg = 'Your value has been updated';       
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                        __($msg)
                );
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('<ext>_CustomEntity/', ['_current' => true]); 
    }   

}
```